# WSA com.android.camera2 Crash on start

Tags: java, android, windows-subsystem-for-android

On start of com.android.camera2
using command:
monkey -p com.android.camera2 -v 500
crashes before UI shown
[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jiLp.png)
[system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONy99.png)

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: WSA Version 2203.40000.3.0

Comment: Please don't use comments to add to your question. Just [edit] the question and add your details. You should also show some code that reproduces the problem. Also, output like errors and stacktraces should be included in the Question as _text_ not an unsearchable image. Take the [tour] if you haven't already to get an idea of how this SE works.